# Why do Captain Aldis' men attack me on sight?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I am not quite sure which quest or which action might have started this, but this is what happens right now:

I enter Solitude (through the door at the foot of the cliff) and walk towards the slope leading up to the Fletcher and the Blacksmith. I can interact with the *regular* Solitude Guards without any problems, but as soon as I walk through the arch between the Fletcher and the Blacksmith and enter the courtyard, the "special" Solitude Guards standing in front of the big door on the left spot me and attack me. After that, all the regular Guards also attack me.

I have no bounty on me in any of the holds, and the Guards do not even give me an option to surrender.

**Why do the Guards in the Solitude Courtyard attack me on sight, and how can I stop it (preferably without violence)?**

Comment: Captain Aldis is linked to Roggvir's execution. Did you interfere with the execution at all?

Comment: I did not, I ignored it. Also, the problem did not start after the execution, it started only much later.

Comment: Are you a Stormcloak?

Comment: Question; prior to these hostile guards, had you been working on the Dark Brotherhood quest line? I know I had a similar issue after impersonating a chef... I decided discretion was the better part of valor and just booked it when the script spawned the guards on the upper walkway, and they stayed there, hostile, for a *long* time. It prevented me from fast travelling out of Solitude for the longest time...

Comment: I am not a Stormcloak, I have kept out of that conflict. The woman from the Dark Brotherhood has abducted me and I killed one of the three hostages, but I have not pursued the questline any further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to a far away place and sleep for a week.  This should reset that cell and fix any NPC oddities.  I had this happen to me with Whiterun's jarl.